# PHP query error when searching for a value equal to a Varchar that contains numbers and letters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `VARCHAR` that contains numbers and letters and I need to find it on a `MySql Database` using `PHP`.
If the `VARCHAR` contains only numbers the `PHP` works fine but when I add also letters to the `VARCHAR` (so something like `38aC39`) the query returns a 500 Internal Server Error (I can't enable errors).

This is how I search for the value on the DB:

```
  $guid = $_GET['guid'];

  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM account WHERE guid='$guid'");
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: `echo $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM account WHERE guid='$guid'");` and what do you see?

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari sorry but I can't, even if I enable error logging I still get the 500 Internal Server Error (It's a server related problem)

Comment: Have you checked that `$con` is a valid connection?

Comment: Your code is open to sql injection